# How to stop methods put() and take() from 'endless waiting'?

Tags: java, queue, blockingqueue

In `BlockingQueue` implementations we know that methods `put()` and `take()` have blocking nature.

What is your advice in solving their endless **wait state**? What if there are no more items to read and `take()` is called for example. My program will run forever. How would you solve this? Any tips?

Comment: You can set some `exit message` at the end of your producer producing all data. On consumer side you can check that message is exit, then do exit from program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`offer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer(E,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) and [`poll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) methods of the `BLockingQueue`. They allow you to specify a timeout for both operations.

```java
// returns false if it could not push after 1 second
blockingQueue.offer(5, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

/// returns null if no item was received after 1 second
blockingQueue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If you don't want a timeout you can use the overloaded methods which will return immediately with the same return behavior ([`offer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer(E)) `poll`)

```java
// returns false if it could not push
blockingQueue.offer(5);

/// returns null if no item was received
blockingQueue.poll();
```

Be careful about checking if the return of `poll` is null. Depending on the structure of the project, you might want to look into java [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to help with proper null checking.

Comment: But they are blocking methods, right? They will act as if wait/notify was called? Cuz I used offer and poll in non blocking implementations..

Comment: Yes they will block until the timeout is reached before returning anything.

Comment: Interesting, so there is different implementation for these method in let's say classes ArrayDeque and ArrayBlockingQueue :)

Comment: You could use also use the overloaded methods which do not take the timeout arguments.